# Regularity theory for $H^k$ space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces

Lat $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbf{R}^n$ with smooth boundary.
Let $a(u,v)=\int_\Omega \Sigma a_{ij}\partial_iu\partial_jv+cuv$
where $a_{ij}$ and $c$ are smooth functions on $\bar{\Omega}$ and $a_{ij}$ satisfies uniform ellipticity condition.

Question: If $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ and $f \in H^k(\Omega)$ satisfying $a(u,v)=\int_{\Omega} fv$ for all $v\in H^1_0(\Omega)$

How to prove $u\in H^{k+2}$?

What about in the case of $u\in H^1$? Prove it to be $u\in H^{k+2}$.

Comment: All the result can be found in section 8.4 of Gilbarg-Trudinger. The proof involve the estimate of the difference quotient of $u$.